# How to create a submenu especific shortcut?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

I've recently been making my way into 2.8 and I've been wondering if there is a way to link keys exclusively to submenus. Let's say I want to shotcut "Clear Seams" to the "C" key in the UV menu, in the Edit Mode. Something similar to how you can double tap "U" to Unwrap a mesh.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Open any menu you would like to have assigned a shortcut to. Right click on the menu item to assign a shortcut.

[image]